# Making OpenGL Camera Look At A Point

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glulookat

I'm working on a game in Java using LWJGL and I'm trying to make it rotate to look at a point in 3D space. I have tried every "lookAt" method I can find on the internet, But I just can't get it to work (The camera just doesn't look in the right direction).

Could you help me figure out how to do this?

EDIT:

Figured it out, Just needed to invert the matrix. Here is the final code if you were having the same issue:

```
public static Matrix4f lookAt(Vector3f eye, Vector3f center, Vector3f up) {
          Vector3f forward = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
          Vector3f.sub(center, eye, forward);
          forward.normalise();

          Vector3f side = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
          Vector3f.cross(forward, up, side);
          side.normalise();

          Vector3f.cross(side, forward, up);

          Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
          matrix.m00 = side.x;
          matrix.m01 = side.y;
          matrix.m02 = side.z;
          matrix.m10 = up.x;
          matrix.m11 = up.y;
          matrix.m12 = up.z;
          matrix.m20 = -forward.x;
          matrix.m21 = -forward.y;
          matrix.m22 = -forward.z;
          matrix.invert();

          return matrix;
       }
```

Comment: Cameras don't look at points. The camera (there is only one, and it's not even a real object, just a concept) always stays in the same place, and the world moves around it.

Comment: Did you try the `gluLookAt()` method? See here: http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/glu/Project.html.

Comment: I think gluLookAt() is deprecated (Correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Figured it out. Just needed to invert the matrix.

Comment: @Robo11 Using Inversion in view matrix is not a correct solution. You have an error elsewhere. What is your matrix layout (column / row) ?

Comment: @immibis Thats not necessary true. You can move camera and it is even better, than moving world via world matrix.

Comment: @MartinPerry sure, you can do that in your own shaders, but OpenGL has no built-in concept of moving the camera.

Comment: Currently your camera is set in the 0,0,0 point. Your implementation lacks the -translation part.